# Where is the discoveryfake defined in k8s discovery interface?

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-testing

While I'm reading how to test on k8s with the fake client on this [link](https://itnext.io/testing-kubernetes-go-applications-f1f87502b6ef), I noticed this function, which, IIUC, assigns a faked server version to the faked k8s cluster.

```
k8s.clientset.Discovery().(*discoveryfake.FakeDiscovery).FakedServerVersion = &version.Info{
                    Major: expectedMajor,
                    Minor: expectedMinor,
            }
```

I'm trying to understand what this `*discoveryfake.FakeDiscovery` code means.
`k8s.clientset.Discovery()` returns `DiscoveryInterface` ([defined here](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.2/discovery#DiscoveryInterface)), but I cannot find `*discoveryfake` field.

What does `Discovery().(*discoveryfake.FakeDiscovery)` mean?

Comment: It's a [type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15).

Answer (score 1):

It's a [type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15), as @peter suggested in the comment.